# how to inherit a class with templates?

Tags: c++

Why would the following work just fine:

```
class a
{
   public:
    int n;
};

class b : public a
{
 public:
  b()
  {
      n = 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
}
```

but this does not work:

```
template <class T>
class a
{
   public:
      int n;
};

template <class T>
class b : public a<T>
{
   public:
    b()
    {
       n = 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

and gives the following error:

```
 1.cpp: In constructor ‘b<T>::b()’:
 1.cpp:14: error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope
```

and how would one inherit a template class while being able to use its base members and keep the type generic?

Answer (score 3):

You need to qualify it with "*this*" or with a "*using*" directive (or explicitly with the base class qualification).

**In a nutshell**: that variable is a *nondependent type* (**non-dependent on the T of the template class**), **the compiler doesn't look into a dependent type (your a< T >) when looking for declarations for a nondependent type**.

`this->n`, since "this" refers to a dependent class, works. The same with the other methods I listed.

---

References:

Faq here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html
Live example here: http://ideone.com/nsw4XJ